# how to remove console.log during production in reactjs created with `create-react-app`

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

i have create app using npx `create-react-app` i want to remove `console.log()` during production but i googled i found this `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console` plugin configured using this link https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console/#via-babelrc-recommended unfortunatly it does't seem workout for me. Note i create .babelrc file manually in my root dir.

Comment: What do you mean by removing? You could just `window.console.log = () => null`.

Comment: ``console.log`` works just to display information in the console. If you never call it, nothing should appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- step 1: npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev
- step 2: `npm run eject`
- step 3 : Edit package.json file

  ```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          "transform-remove-console"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- step 4 : `npm run build`